# can I define a table variable in the package body, and use it in the procedures?

Tags: oracle

I would like to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_refresh_pkg AS

    TYPE r_data IS RECORD (
        ID       CHAR(10),
        STATUS   CHAR(12),
        "DATA"       CLOB
        );
    TYPE t_data IS TABLE OF r_data;

    l_data t_data;

    /** forward declarations */
    PROCEDURE firstProc;
    PROCEDURE secondProc;
    PROCEDURE thirdProc;

/** main method call */
PROCEDURE refresh AS
    BEGIN
        -- clean out old data
        DELETE FROM target_table;
            COMMIT;

        -- fetch working dataset
        SELECT id, status, "data"
        BULK COLLECT INTO l_data
        FROM source_table
        WHERE status <> 'INITIAL';

        -- call individual inserts
        firstProc;
        secondProc;
        thirdProc;


    END refresh;
[... proc definitions, etc ...]
```

Am I going about this the right way?  My package isn't compiling; I'm getting a "table or view doesn't exist" error.  I can't tell if it's referring to the table variable.

Comment: Well, which line is giving the error?

Comment: Do you have direct grants on all the tables?  Remember, when you compile a stored procedure, all roles are disabled, so, grants on tables must be directly to the user, not via a role.

Comment: The error isn't coming from any of these lines.  The error is occurring during the definition of "firstProc", etc, where I'm trying to query the l_data table.  I had thought that declaring the table in the package made it accessible to all the procs.  And, the first one doesn't trip an error, so I don't know.